# How to set up a C++ function so that it can be used by p/invoke?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllimport, extern

Hopefully this is a brainlessly easy question, but it shows my lack of expertise with C++.  I'm a C# programmer, and I've done extensive work with P/Invoke in the past with other people's C++/C dlls.  However, this time I've decided to write a wrapper C++ dll (unmanaged) myself, and am then calling my wrapper dll from C#.

The problem I am immediately running into is that I am unable to define a C++ function that can be found by p/invoke.  I don't know what the syntax for this is, but here's what I'm trying so far:

```
extern bool __cdecl TestFunc()
{
  return true;
}
```

Originally I simply had this, but it did not work either:

```
bool TestFunc()
{
  return true;
}
```

And then on the C# side, I have:

```
    public const string InterfaceLibrary = @"Plugins\TestDLL.dll";

    [DllImport( InterfaceLibrary, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
        EntryPoint = "TestFunc" ), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    internal static extern bool TestFunc();
```

Everything compiles, but when I execute this C# p/invoke call, I get a System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'TestFunc' in DLL 'Plugins\TestDLL.dll'.

Surely this must be something incredibly simple on the C++ end that I just don't know the syntax for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll want to use `extern "C"` as well as `__declspec(export)`, like so:

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)  bool TestFunc()
{
    return true;
}
```

For full details, see [MSDN on Marshalling Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446538.aspx).

Comment: Perfect, that did it!  I had also tried just having extern "C" in the past, but that did not work.  It fails until the _declspec(dllexport) is added in.

Answer (score 7):

Extending Reed's correct answer.

Another issue you can run into when exposing a C++ function via PInvoke is using invalid types.  PInvoke can really only support marshalling of primitive types and plain old data struct / class types.

For example, suppose TestFunc had the following signature

```
void TestFunc(std::string input);
```

Even adding extern "C" and `__declspec(dllexport)` would not be enough to expose the C++ function.  Instead you would need to create a helper function which exposed only PInvoke compatible types and then called into the main function.  For example

```
void TestFunc(const std::string& input) { ... }

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)  void TestFuncWrapper(char* pInput) {
  std::string input(pInput);
  TestFunc(input);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's precisely this sort of reason that I'm writing a wrapper C++ dll, rather than trying to call all of the functions I need directly.  My goal is to create a simpler interface for P/Invoke, while letting all the needed complexity with callbacks and complex types, etc, remain on the C++ side.  Good points!

Comment: @x4000, I've taken the exact same approach before.  Except instead of a new DLL, I just added the wrapper functions to the same DLL.  More DLL's would have been cleaner.

Comment: The initial DLL that I'm wrappering is by a third party, so that wasn't an option for me.  But you're right, I think it's cleaner in many respects to separate the wrappers from the content being wrappered when possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to expose this function with `extern "C"` otherwise the name gets mangled.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ compiler modifies the names of your functions to incorporate information about the parameters and return types. This is called name mangling. On the other hand, the C compiler doesn't mangle your function names.

You can tell the C++ compiler to work as a C compiler using `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool TestFunc { return true; }
```

To call functions from C# using P/Invoke, your names must not be mangled. Therefore, you can actually export C functions to C#. If you want the functionality to be implemented in C++, you can write a C function that just calls the C++ function implementing the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Do something likes this:

```
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
```

And then declare any function with the EXPORT keyword, for example an c++ function

```
BOOL getString(TCHAR* string, DWORD size);
```

would become

```
EXPORT BOOL getString(TCHAR* string, DWORD size);
```

then the fun part: Go to your VS console and type :

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS <PATH_TO_GENERATED_DLL>
```

and you'l see the mangled name and ordinal of all your easily exported functions, then it's just an matter o pInvoking them

Answer (score 0):

Build all project with Win32 platform and appropriate bit (e.g. x86 or x64) build option.