# System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point

Tags: c#, vb6

I have convert VB6 to c# while executing it generate this error

**FROM VB6**

```
Declare Function OpenCommPort Lib "C:\Program Files\MR705API.dll" Alias "?OpenCommPort@@YGHPADPAPAX@Z" (ByVal PortName As String, ByRef hCom As Long) As Long
Declare Function CloseCommPort Lib "C:\Program Files\MR705API.dll" Alias "?CloseCommPort@@YGHPAX@Z" (ByVal hCom As Long) As Long
Declare Function SetLED Lib "C:\Program Files\MR705API.dll" Alias "?SetLED@@YGHPAXEE@Z" (ByVal hCom As Long, ByVal Led As Byte, ByVal Addr As Byte) As Long
Declare Function ActiveBuzzer Lib "C:\Program Files\MR705API.dll" Alias "?ActiveBuzzer@@YGHPAXEE@Z" (ByVal hCom As Long, ByVal DelayTime As Byte, ByVal Addr As Byte) As Long
Declare Function Iso14443Reqa Lib "C:\Program Files\MR705API.dll" Alias "?Iso14443Reqa@@YGHPAXEPAEE@Z" (ByVal hCom As Long, ByVal ReqAMode As Byte, ByVal ATQ As String, ByVal Addr As Byte) As Long
Declare Function Iso14443Anticoll Lib "C:\Program Files\MR705API.dll" Alias "?Iso14443Anticoll@@YGHPAXEPAE1E@Z" (ByVal hCom As Long, ByVal AnticollMode As Byte, ByVal Uid As String, ByVal MultiTag As String, ByVal Addr As Byte) As Long
```

**IN C#**

```
        [DllImport ("MR705API.dll")]
        public static extern long OpenCommPort(String portName, ref long hCom ); 

        [DllImport ("MR705API.dll")]
        public static extern long CloseCommPort(long hCom);

        [DllImport ("MR705API.dll")]
        public static extern long SetLED(long hCom, byte Led , byte Addr);

        [DllImport ("MR705API.dll")]
        public static extern long ActiveBuzzer (long hcom, byte DelayTime, byte Addr);

        [DllImport ("MR705API.dll")]
        public static extern long Iso14443Reqa (long hcom, byte ReqAMode, string ATQ, byte Addr);
```

**And how I use it..**

```
public void doReader() {

            Result = OpenCommPort("COM9", ref HANDLE);
            ....
            ....
}
```

**Exception**

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'OpenCommPort' in DLL 'MR705API.dll'.

   at TrueReader.MainForm.OpenCommPort(String portName, Int64& hCom)
   at TrueReader.MainForm.doReader() in c:\Users\sattha\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\TrueReader\TrueReader\MainForm.cs:line 59
   at TrueReader.MainForm.Timer1Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\sattha\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\TrueReader\TrueReader\MainForm.cs:line 54
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at TrueReader.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\sattha\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\TrueReader\TrueReader\Program.cs:line 27
```

Can any one guide me, what did I do wrong?? or what did I miss.

I don't know how this .dll wrote and in which languages.

but it had used in VB6 before.

Comment: a long in VB6 would equate to In32 in .NET, so your PInvokes are wrong.  if it cant find a match for the wrong sig, that error would result

Comment: @Plutonix you mean I have to change from long to int32 ?

Comment: @Plutonix it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Your original VB6 imports look like they are referring to c++ _[mangled names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)_. If so I'm not sure your c# PInvoke declarations are incorrect.

Comment: Though the question talks about c++, the answer may be found here _[P/Invoking function via a mangled name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804494/p-invoking-function-via-a-mangled-name)_.  Essentially you need to include the `mangled name` in the PInvoke declaration

Comment: @MickyDuncan how can I get mangled name can I generate it by myself?

Comment: Don't you have the mangled names right there in the VB6 source?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError you mean this term in VB6 ... Alias "?OpenCommPort@@YGHPADPAPAX@Z" ...

Comment: Yes, that is what I am referring to.

Comment: Thankyou all of you guys it seem that is the answer of this error.

However, it generate a new Exception >..< ... system.accessviolationexception attempted to read or write protected memory

Comment: @JongzPuangput Yes the mangled names can be found in the VB6 original code.  e.g. ""?OpenCommPort@@YGHPADPAPAX@Z""

Comment: @JongzPuangput _"system.accessviolationexception attempted to read or write protected memory"_ - is usually an indication of an incorrect p-invoke declarion.  e.g. incorrect `int` lengths; missing `out` `params`; pointers; and so forth

Comment: @micky some params is missing or wrong input params in some functions right?

Comment: @JongzPuangput _"some params is missing.."_ - yes that can do it too.  Take a look at [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) for some examples.  Sadly, I and pinvoke.net dont know anything about `MR705API.dll` so I can't help with the actual pinvoke declarations.  Wishing you well

Comment: @micky i'm missing ref keyword so it work now thank kk

Comment: @JongzPuangput That's great! Feel free to post an `answer` to your own question below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> YOU SHOULD DEFINE ENTRY POINT FOR EACH DLLIMPORT FUNCTIONS

Just copy entry point from `Alias` from your VB6 code to C#

**FOR EXAMPLE... "OpenCommPort" in VB6**

> Alias "?OpenCommPort@@YGHPADPAPAX@Z"

**TO -> "OpenCommPort" in C#**

```
[DllImport ("MR705API.dll",
EntryPoint="?OpenCommPort@@YGHPADPAPAX@Z")]
public static extern int OpenCommPort(string portName, ref int hCom);
```

**ADDINTIONAL**

`long` in **VB6** equivalent to `int` in **C#**